Is there a way to get a list of Release Updates that have Test Run enabled and disabled?
I can go to Setup -> Release Updates and review all the updates and see that some have TEST RUN SUPPORTED.  What I can't easily see is a list of which ones I have enabled and which ones I do not.  I have to click on each one to check the status (unless I'm missing something). I need to enable all the options in a least three test orgs and it's extremely tedious to have to check each one to make sure I have it enabled.  It would be great if I could get a list somewhere of all those at that test mode and whether it is disable or enable.  Anyone know if that be be found anywere?

Too bad Sf doesn't expose that field in ReleaseUpdate. This is what I dislike that they have all of this info and do half baked work sometimes in making that availabsle. One other great example is Inactive picklist values. They have it but doesn't expose it.
